# Home in page/post not refer to homepage

Tags: homepage, home-url

I really need help.

I'm using Private Lawyer theme, and I'm having this problem,

Eg:  Home >> Photo Gallery

the "home" not refer to my homepage. when I click it, it refer back to photo gallery page.
I view the source code behind and yes, it did not link to homepage.

how to change it back to homepage? anyone please help, thankyouuu!

*it is not the home in main menu above.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_home_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_home_url/) to link to the home page:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_home_url() . '">Home</a>';
```

Comment: where can i view the theme codes to put the code above? sorry i'm newbie.

Comment: @hauralina I don’t know that theme. Search for `>>` with an editor that can search multiple files at once like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: Thankyou toscho for help, but I cant get it bcoz I do the editing through online using wordpress 3.5.1 . I just start it since last two weeks and until now I dont know how to view the code. I only view it through mozilla.

Comment: You have to download the theme directory per FTP, make a backup, edit the file and re-upload it. The built-in theme editor cannot search, and it does not allow editing files in subdirectories.